# How to debug strange behavior when adding to Moment?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So some precursor information. 
The date I am calculating from: `2016-04-11T22:12:36.000Z`

I add 12 hours to it by doing:

```
var time = new Date(d.dateCreated)
time = Number(time)
diff = parseInt(d.time) * 3600
diff = time + diff
```

The calculated differences of the code is:

```
console.log(time,diff)
//result: 1460412756000 1460412799200
```

Then when I run the following code:

```
var m = moment().diff(diff, 'hours')
//Returns 194 hours
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not reading the documentation and utilizing it, that's what you're doing wrong. Sorry to be crass...

You want to do this to your date/time

(from the moment docs -- http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)

```
moment().add(12, 'hours');
```

Comment: I'm so sorry! I should read the docs more closely... I just tunnel visioned on diff...